# d cannot initialize WNDCLASSW, WNDCLASSEX, WNDCLASSEXW window structs

Tags: winapi, window, d

```
WNDCLASS wc; - ok
WNDCLASSA wc; - ok
WNDCLASSW wc; - Error: undefined identifier WNDCLASSW, did you mean alias WNDCLASS?
WNDCLASSEX wc; - Error: undefined identifier WNDCLASSEX, did you mean struct WNDCLASSEXA?
WNDCLASSEXA wc; - ok
WNDCLASSEXW wc; Error: undefined identifier WNDCLASSEXW, did you mean struct WNDCLASSEXA?
```

code:

```
import core.runtime;
import core.sys.windows.windows;
extern(Windows)
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
  WNDCLASSEXA wc;
  return 0;
}
```

I most concerned about WNDCLASSEXW, that is the version I intend to use.

Comment: The error message seems kind of obvious to me. Have you looked in the relevant imported file to see if the type is defined? If it is not, it might just be an oversight and you could write a patch to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple I can define the struct myself:

```
struct WNDCLASSEXW {
  UINT      cbSize;
  UINT      style;
  WNDPROC   lpfnWndProc;
  int       cbClsExtra;
  int       cbWndExtra;
  HINSTANCE hInstance;
  HICON     hIcon;
  HCURSOR   hCursor;
  HBRUSH    hbrBackground;
  LPCWSTR   lpszMenuName;
  LPCWSTR   lpszClassName;
  HICON     hIconSm;
}
```

Comment: Check the windows module and if these structs are missing, submit a pull request please (if there is not already one).

Comment: @DejanLekic: and where should I put such request so it will be actually read by the people who commit to the source ?

Comment: DMD, druntime and phobos are all open-source projects hosted on GitHub.  Maintaned by the following team: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language .